# mixing placeholders, executemany, and table names

Tags: python, executemany

I can iterate through a python object with te following code, however I would like to be able to use placeholders for the schema and table name, normally I do this with `{}.{}` ad the `.format()` methods, but how do you combine the two?

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO schema.table_name (x,y,z) "
                        "values (%s, %s, %s)", top_sample)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is. You can very well use `format` like this:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO {}.{} (x,y,z) values (%s, %s, %s)".format('hello', 'world'), top_sample)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which python you use you can try use `f-string`

```
schema = "schema"
table_name = "table_name"

cur.executemany(f"INSERT INTO {schema}.{table_name} (x,y,z) values (%s, %s, %s)", top_sample)
```

check [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

another option is a simple `format`

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO {schema}.{table_name} (x,y,z) values (%s, %s, %s)".format(schema=schema, table_name=table_name), top_sample)
```

but I find the first option shorter and cleaner

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.executemany(
  """INSERT INTO schema.{table_name} (x,y,z) values (%s, %s, %s)""".format(table_name=your_table_name),
  top_sample
)
```

place your table name in place of your_table_name